# PHP-Login.net Advanced Script - how to allow logged in users access to other pages/"views"?

Tags: php

I am using PHP-Login.net Advanced script and I see how when the user logs in, it goes to the logged_in view.

However, I want the user to be able to then go to another PHP page, but I only want it visible if they are logged in.

Not sure if this would be another "View" of index.php or its own page?

How could I make this work? Thanks!

```
 <?php

/**
 * A simple PHP Login Script / ADVANCED VERSION
 * For more versions (one-file, minimal, framework-like) visit http://www.php-login.net
 *
 * @author Panique
 * @link http://www.php-login[dot]net
 */

// check for minimum PHP version
if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.7', '<')) {
    exit('Sorry, this script does not run on a PHP version smaller than 5.3.7 !');
} else if (version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.5.0', '<')) {
    // if you are using PHP 5.3 or PHP 5.4 you have to include the password_api_compatibility_library.php
    // (this library adds the PHP 5.5 password hashing functions to older versions of PHP)
    require_once('libraries/password_compatibility_library.php');
}
// include the config
require_once('config/config.php');

// include the to-be-used language, english by default. feel free to translate your project and include something else
require_once('translations/en.php');

// include the PHPMailer library
require_once('libraries/PHPMailer.php');

// load the login class
require_once('classes/Login.php');

// create a login object. when this object is created, it will do all login/logout stuff automatically
// so this single line handles the entire login process.
$login = new Login();

// ... ask if we are logged in here:
if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    // the user is logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are logged in" view.
    include("views/logged_in.php");

} else {
    // the user is not logged in. you can do whatever you want here.
    // for demonstration purposes, we simply show the "you are not logged in"
view.
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
 ?>
```

Comment: Read about `$_SESSION` and `header('Location: ..');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if I reuse this code on the second logged in page, it will work - if logged in = true, display the page, if not true, display the view of the log in page.

So for example, lets say my second "logged in only" page is index2.php, I would have

```
 <?php 

if ($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true) {
    // the user is logged in, display this page 

    include("views/index2.php");

} else {
    // the user is not logged in

view.
    include("views/not_logged_in.php");
}
?>
```

Okay it looks like by using this for the "index2.php" page, it creates a new session because I have to log in and out 2x ....

If i click logout, it shows the login screen, but then if I go back to "index2.php" directly, it shows i am still logged in

This is not the correct solution ....

Answer (score 0):

Its not necessary to use the views only, put a check on any user base php file.
Check if they are logged in or not.

*example*

```
if(!$_SESSION['user_logged_in']){
    echo "<h2>Restricted page..</h2>";
    exit;
}else{
    echo "Member Logged-In";
}
```